# Building Boost on OpenVMs

Tags: c++, boost, openvms

I’m hoping  to port an application to open vms using HP C++7.3, but at the minute just trying out a few examples to establish if it's a potential way forward but a bit stuck.  Being completely new to open vms it's being a lot of fun so far.

For starters I've not got very far building boost as a whole, after some googling I found a few mentions of people having dcl scripts to build boost but no actual scripts.   I don’t suppose anyone has any or can pint me to some.  I ‘only’ need asio and threading.

Currently I’m just trying to compile the asio chat examples.  And as I said I’m completely new to VMS and the compiler, I managed to get a few things to compile but now get a  “could not open source file "sys/select.h"’, a bit of googling suggests I may need to have an HP porting library installed or maybe I’m just missing an prepocessor directive to include the correct code, can’t see anything obvious in socket_types.hpp to set?

Any pointers in the right general direction would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You get my pity upvote.  I suspect you will have to contact people who mention being able to do these things directly and ask them for assistance.  Or contact your compiler vendor for support.

Comment: @MK I think so too.  Unfortunately I need to understand the risk involved pretty soon and doesn't look like I'm going to get a reply soon, thought I'd try my luck here.  Otherwise I'll have to assume a worst case scenario of starting from scratch :-(

Comment: I've dealt a little bit with building modern apps on OpenVMS, but C, not C++.  It is doable, but non-trivial and having support contract with a compiler vendor is essential in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

No answers since the questio is too open ended and in a realm I know little about.
Just some thoughts.

Select can be provided by the OpenVMS TCPIP services (aka UCX), or other TCP stack.
At the dcl prompt try:  $ HELP TCPIP_Services Programming_Interfaces Socket_API

Async programming on OpenVMS is typically 'event driven'. 
Google for SYS$QIO and AST

There is a public access OpenVMS system which holds 'NOTES FILES' (pre-cursor to web-forums)
Try TELNET to EISNER.DECUS.ORG and you'll get sign up instructions.
Once you are in find your way to the PORTING_TO_VMS conference 
Once in the NOTES conference you can issue the command DIRECTORY or DIR/TIT=xxx
Unfortunately there is not topic for select, but you can find some interesting 
reading using NOTES> SEARCH "select(" followed by repeated SEARCH commands)
( $ NOTES ... OPEN PORT ... SEARCH "select(" ... SEARCH [] ... SEARCH ... )

The PERL folks did an admirable job getting open stuff to work on OpenVMS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

boost library on OpenVMS can be used directly from headers.
I remember one thing to make sure was that BOOST logical is defined concealed, so the relative-includes work.